# How to change my phone number on Facetime and iMessage?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, messages, facetime

So I have already changed my number on my Apple ID and on my Gmail, but when I log in with my Apple ID on Facetime and iMessage it still has my old phone number.I restarted my phone but still the same.I look forward to your answers and I would really but really appreciate if you can help me!

Comment: In the settings app - is the phone number for your phone the same number as you see in settings for messages? Fix the former first and the second should follow.

Answer (score -1):

Remove a phone number from an Apple ID, sign out of FaceTime and Messages on your iPhone:
1. Settings > Messages > Send & Receive. Tap your Apple ID, then tap Sign Out.
2. Settings > FaceTime. Tap your Apple ID, then tap Sign Out.

Comment: This appears to only be a partial answer.  Can you edit it to add complete info, as asked in the question, about how to change a phone number on Facetime and Messages?